# how to zip files that unzipped - shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory that I have been storing a lot of files so I'm working on a script to watch the disk space if it gets more than 80% then it will compress the files.
all the files end with file.# 
my question is how to zip all files that end with a number without zipping the zipped files
I did the most of the script but I'm stuck with at this point
please your help

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the files that are outputted by this command `find . -not -name "*.zip"`.

Find is a command that is used well, to "find" files based on various criteria.

You can read more about it using `man find` or (online version) [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the `zip` command with `-x` argument to exclude already zipped files from being added to the compressed archive. The command will look like:

```
zip -r compressed.zip . -x "*.zip"
```